# Upload without upload button in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin

I want to select file to upload then let user to do some other things and then when he clicks a submit button I want to execute the actual upload.

How can I excute/start the upload without using the upload button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `submitUpload()` in `Upload` that does the trick.